# Gesture recognizer on SpriteKIt takes ages to get the swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am using a GestureRecognizer to detect  a swipe to transition to a new Scene. Why it takes ages to get the action?

```
-(void) handleSwipeRight:( UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
        // do something if the swipe right had exactly 2 fingers involved
        SKScene *sampleScene = [[Right alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition flipVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
        [self.view presentScene:sampleScene transition:transition];

}
```

Comment: What's the time translation to "ages"? Have you considered that it is not the gesture taking long but rather the loading of your new scene?